# in pycharm, how can i specify the function return types outside the function

Tags: python, pycharm

My idea is to decorate the function with a decorator and then return other objects. Because I can not specify the return type in the function, so I would like to know if there is any way to specify in the decorator, thanks very much. here is the sample code:

```
class DemoObject(object):
    """
    DEMO OBJECT
    """
    def say(self):
        print 'i am in demo object'


def demo_decorator(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return DemoObject()

    return wrapper


@demo_decorator
def demo_fun():
    a = 1
    b = 2

demo_fun().say()
```

I want specify the demo_fun return types but not use ":rtype: xxx" in demo_fun docs, tks.

Comment: My goal is to be able to implement automatic prompts within the pycharm IDE

Comment: You could use type hints, which was recently implemented with [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) in Python 3.5.  Alternatively, functions are objects, you can just set a property on them, like `def a(): return ''; a.return_type = str`

Comment: thank you  Darthfett, but i dont want hints in function definition, because I should write very much function will use.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.  Can you elaborate further?  Type Hints would allow a tool (like pycharm) to read the code and annotate type information.  Setting attributes allows you to access it programmatically.  It should cover all use cases I can think of.

Comment: thank you very much,I'm so sorry that my English is so bad that I can not express my intention.  I'll re-describe my question later.

Comment: I am reading the code in more detail now.  It looks like you are saying you would like to return a value from a function that does not currently return one, but without changing the original function.  Are you saying you want to avoid changing the function signature that shows up to give you type hints when using an IDE (like pycharm)?

Comment: yes its what I want :)

Comment: Although it is not enough, but little effect

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  I can't think of a good use case, and I don't know any way to trick Pycharm into showing the wrong return type (or lack of any return type).

Comment: @CaseyKuball You are right, I found my mistake is extremely stupid, I have given up, thank you very much, and at the same time I feel sorry for my late reply

Comment: No worries, sorry to hear that you were not able to explain what you were trying to accomplish.  Hope you've at least learned *something* even if you couldn't get what you needed here... :)